# How to map geo location based on one or all of these services

Tags: maps, geotagging

I'm looking for a solution to map one or all of the following Flickr, twitter, vimeo, by exif, keywords or whatever to google maps. I'm trying to show a map of my location from updating social sites.

Answer (score 1):

If each of the services you want [supports GeoRSS](http://georss.org/), then you can actually build such a map with zero coding whatsoever!  This is because Google Maps supports mapping a GeoRSS feed directly. All you have to do is type the URL of the RSS feed with the GeoRSS data within, into the box on Google maps.  Here's an example of the [feed from my What's The Harm? website](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&geocode=&q=http:%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2FWhatsTheHarm) mapped in Google Maps.

Now you mention several services there, each of which whould presumably have its own GeoRSS feed.  What you would need to do is merge the feeds together before handing the resulting feed to Google Maps.  There are a variety of ways to do this, one quick point-and-click way is via [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com).  Search for "merge feed" or "merge RSS" on there and you can find many examples that you can copy and modify.

Yahoo Pipes also has functionality to *add* GeoRSS coding to feeds that don't have it already.  You could use that to bring in data like blog posts and son on that might not be GeoRSS.  Look under "Operators" for the "Location Extractor" widget.

As for the websites you mentioned:

- Flickr: Yes. Make sure you map your photos, and use the feed marked "geoFeed".
- twitter: There's a service called [GeoTwitter](http://geotwitter.net) that can add this for you.
- vimeo: It doesn't appear they support it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice greasemonkey [script](http://txfx.net/2005/05/17/flickr-google-maps-geobloggers/) to ease geotagging on Flickr.